# Adding color disrupts the transitions in a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

If I create a simple scatterplot and add an animation, I get a beautiful "smooth" transition between states

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

data("diamonds")

ggplot(diamonds) +
 aes(carat, price) +
 geom_point() +
 transition_states(clarity)
```

[image: Smooth transition]

But if I want to differentiate the points by color, the "smooth" transition is now lost.

```
ggplot(diamonds) +
 aes(carat, price, color = clarity) +
 geom_point() +
 transition_states(clarity)
```

[image: Abrupt transition]

Why does this happen? How can I put it back? (I tried to add eases, but with no result)

Comment: The reasons are explained in the object permanence part of the gganimate [vignette](https://gganimate.com/articles/gganimate.html#object-permanence-1).

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the comment from @teunbrand, read the [object permanence](https://gganimate.com/articles/gganimate.html#object-permanence-1) section of the vignette and you will see the same thing.  The TL;DR is to specify the `group=` aesthetic to apply to the entire dataset - like `group=1`.

```
ggplot(diamonds) +
  aes(carat, price, color=clarity, group=1) +
  geom_point() +
  transition_states(clarity)
```

[image]

The reason it happens (practically-speaking) is that the smoothing for the animations happens using the `group=` aesthetic.  Without defining a `group=` aesthetic, all observations belong to the same "group".  The transition states specify `clarity`, so the animations smooth for *all observations* along the clarity column - transitioning from one clarity set to another.

When you define `color=` or other aesthetic across this discrete value, `ggplot2` plots by cutting the data into groups according to the color specification.  Effectively, specifying `color=clarity` also defines `group=clarity`.  The animation is then made by smoothing from one value of clarity to the next *within each group*.  Since every group contains only one value for clarity... you're smoothing from one transition state to an identical one and get no animation.

Therefore, the fix is to define for `gganimate` that even though you cut the data into groups for color, the `group=` aesthetic should still be defined across the entire dataset.  You can do this by setting the `group=` aesthetic to any value.  Here, I'm using `group=1`, but you can literally assign that to anything unchanging: `group="happyfuntime"` will work just the same.